# OpenGL Application crashes when accessing Assimp Texture Coordinate Data

Tags: c++, assimp

I am trying to access the Texture Coordinate of a Cube model made in blender.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < mMesh->mNumVertices; i++) {
    std::cout << mMesh->mTextureCoords[i][0].x << " " << mMesh->mTextureCoords[i][0].y << std::endl;
}
```

Why is this happening.
The application window launches but the red color background doesnt display.
And the first coords also get printed 
`0 1`

How do i solve this.

Removing this code doesn't lead to a crash.

Comment: Did you missed up first and second array arguments of `mTextureCoords` (e.g. `mTextureCoords[0][i]`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < mMesh->mNumVertices; i++)
{
    std::cout << mMesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x << " " << mMesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y << std::endl;
}
```

Looks like you messed up the first and second array arguments. Also, it is good practice to check if the mesh has texture coordinates or not. Then the code becomes

```cpp
if (mMesh->HasTextureCoords(0)) //HasTextureCoords is an assimp function
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mMesh->mNumVertices; i++)
    {
        std::cout << mMesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x << " " << mMesh- >mTextureCoords[0][i].y << std::endl;
    }
}
```